# What's the meaning of `input[text]` selector?

Tags: css

I know that `input[type="text']` is used to select `<input type="text"/>`, what does `input[text]` mean?

This snippet appear in angular tutorial:

```
body, input[text], button {
    color: #888;
    font-weight: Cambria, Georgia;
}
```

[Angular tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt0) (At buttom of that page)

Comment: page not found on your tutorial...

Comment: Fixed. The code resides at bottom of that page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input[text]` means that inputs with attribute `text` assigned to whatever will be returned:

```
<input text="123">
<input text="">
<input text>
```

but this won't be

```
<input type="text">
```

Proof:

```js
console.log(document.querySelectorAll('input[text]'))
```

```html
<input text="123">
<input text="">
<input text>
<input type="text">
```

Why it is like that in Angular tutorial? Probably a simple typo. They anyway don't have inputs in the provided example.